# How to "get/download" data/json from a dataTask(with: request)

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I want to get the progress of the download of a json file. My current code uses a completion handler that looks like this:

```
        let dataTask = downloadSession.dataTask(with: request){   
        data,response,error in                                                       

        // do....try here I handle the json file successfully           

        }

        dataTask.resume()
```

The problem is that I am trying to use URLSessionDataDelegate and the function:

```
   func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
         displayAlertMessage(message: "Data was received")
    }
```

The function above never gets call. Based on the research that I have done on the web the reason behind it is that the Handler blocks it and don't let the delegate work the way is supposed to. So how can I solve this issue?

I need the data from the handler but I also want the progress of the download from the URLSessionDataDelegate. What to do? Is there a way to get both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use one kind of API – either block based or delegate based.

Consider

- Is the JSON such a large file that you need a percental progress indicator?
- Is the indeterminate spinning indicator sufficient?

In iOS you could simply use `isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` of `UIApplication`

Comment: Hi Vadian, thanks for the quick response, that is the exact answer I was looking for. I have been struggling with this for 3 days now. The json file is gonna be around a 100 objects. The spinning indicator will be more than sufficient.... Is there any link or tutorial on how to get that to work? thanks

Comment: Have you searched *UIProgressView URLSession* or *NSProgressIndicator URLSession* here on SO?

Comment: I have with UIProgressView(that is what I was currently using) but no NSProgressIndicator URLSession. I will take a look at it. I won't accept your answer yet because I want to wait to see if some else have a possible solution to my issue but I really appreciate your help. If there is no possible way to get this working with my current code situation then your answer will be the correct one. thanks

Comment: The isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible took care of my problem, so thanks again for the answer Vadian. For others running with the same issue. This tutorials about isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible are worth taking a look at:

Comment: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-activity-indicator-status-bar-ios8-swift